# set state of GtkToggleButton without triggering callback

Tags: gtk

I would like to set the state of a GtkToggleButton, without causing it to emit any signals. Is this possible?

This causes the signal to be emitted, as I would expect from the docs (C code):

```
GtkToggleButton* but;
gboolean state = get_some_data();
gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(but), state);
```

I also tried this, which has the same effect:

```
g_object_set(but,"active", state, NULL);
```

Any thoughts? (I'm totally new to GTK, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.) Thanks!

I (belatedly) discovered the signal-blocking mechanism:

```
g_signal_handlers_block_by_func( but, G_CALLBACK(my_callback), NULL);              
gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(but), c);
g_signal_handlers_unblock_by_func( but, G_CALLBACK(my_callback), NULL);
```

Is this appropriate usage?

Comment: The signal-blocking mechanism has been specifically implemented to do what you are doing: it is not a workaround.

Comment: Regardling `GtkSpinButton`: a new question would be better but... do you mean `gtk_spin_button_set_value` does not emit a `value-changed signal? It will be weird.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my silly question. And double-checking, I see that of course I was wrong about the spinbutton. 

What I was seeing is that the signalling system, by some magic, doesn't allow the spinbutton value callback to itself trigger more callbacks, which is a good thing. 

 I'll edit the question, or maybe just delete it.